# Solving $\Pi^t_i 2 m_i \left(N_i!\right)^{m_i} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, factorial, products

I would like to work out the result of $\Pi^t_i 2 m_i \left(N_i!\right)^{m_i} $.

Here, $t, i, N_i, m_i$ are positive integers.

**My effort:**

$$
\Pi^t_i 2 m_i \left(N_i!\right)^{m_i} 
\implies (2 m_1 \left(N_1!\right)^{m_1}) (2 m_2 \left(N_2!\right)^{m_2}) \ldots (2 m_t \left(N_t!\right)^{m_t})
$$

I do not know how to proceed from here. Is there any shortcut?

Comment: Without giving what $N_i$ and $m_i$ are, there's not much that can be said......

Comment: @T.Bongers, they are positive integers. Are you asking for any more specific information? Could you give an example?

Comment: Without knowing a lot more information about the numbers (do they follow some pattern, are they consecutive, is there a lot of repetition), I doubt that any meaningful answer can be given.

Comment: @T.Bongers, what if $N_i, m_i$ are only prime integers?